# Cannot assert value in Spock

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spock

I have a code that test if the list saved in the repository is updated in the service. The status needs to be updated from `READY` to `DELETED`
but it seems that the `status` returns `null` instead of a ListStatus

Can someone help?

```
    given:
    Long teamId = 1L
    Long listId = 1L


    List() currentList = Mock()
    currentList.status = ListStatus.READY

    listRepository.findByIdAndTeamIdAndStatusIn(listId, teamId, ListStatus.getUserVisibleStatuses()) >> Optional.of(currentList)
    service.fetchValidListtByIdAndTeamId(listId, teamId) >> Optional.of(currentList)

    when:
    service.deleteList(teamId, listId)

    then:
    1 * listRepository.save(currentList) >> { updatedList ->
        assert updatedList.status == status.DELETED
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is so full of errors that my response will probably make assumptions that don't match your use case. I will try however.

First, this line does not compile:

```
List() currentList = Mock()
```

You are declaring a variable, this put simply, should be done by

`type specification` `identifier` = `initializer`

`List()` cannot be a type specification, it is some kind of method call to a method `List()` that should be in the scope of your test.

If we assume that what you meant is

```
List currentList = Mock()
```

The List type in java.lang does not have a `status` property.
I will just assume that the `List` type is your own.

This is just me, but I find it a lot more readable to write

```
def currentList=Mock(List)
```

but both will work.

The next line is where you run into trouble.
`currentList` is not a List implementation. It does not have a member variable for status. It is a mock that respects the interface of `List`. It has a `setStatus()` and a `getStatus()` method. But calling `setStatus(ListStatus.READY)` will not set the internal state of your mock. It does not have internal state, or at least not the internal state of List.

It looks like what you want is to create a Stub of type `List`, that will return `ListStatus.READY` when `getStatus()` is called. You can do this in the following way:

```
def currentList=Stub(List) {
    getStatus() >> ListStatus.READY
}
```

There is a lot of missing boilerplate code for me to run your example and check further possible errors, so I hope this correction will get you in the right direction.

Comment: This is a typical example of what happens if the OP (original poster) publishes just an isolated code snippet instead of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): People trying to help have to speculate, make educated guesses which could be right or wrong. Why does anyone posting a question believe that cutting a snippet out of its context - no class definition, no imports, no package name, no class under test are provided - will do any good? Would it not be easier to provide the whole bundle of classes needed to actually compile and run the test?